# How to visit children of parse tree using antlr4ts rule element labels

Tags: typescript, antlr, antlr4

Summary: How do I get antlr4ts to visit the expressions captured by the rule element labels?

I have the following grammer (.g4) file:

```
grammar datacurator_grammar;

/* This will be the entry point of our parser. */
equation
    :   expression;

expression
    :   NUMBER                                               # Number
    |   left=expression operator=(ADD|SUB) right=expression  # AdditionOrSubtraction
    ;

ADD: '+';
SUB: '-';

NUMBER
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

/* We're going to ignore all white space characters */
WHITESPACE
    :   [ \r\n\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

And I have a Visitor written in TypeScript:

```js
class Visitor extends AbstractParseTreeVisitor<string> implements datacurator_grammarVisitor<string>
{
    visitAdditionOrSubtraction (ctx: AdditionOrSubtractionContext): string
    {
        const left = this.visitChildren(ctx._left)
        const right = this.visitChildren(ctx._right)
        return `( ${left} ${ctx._operator.text} ${right} )`
    }




    protected defaultResult(): string
    {
        return ""
    }

    protected aggregateResult (aggregate: string, next_result: string)
    {
        return aggregate + next_result
    }


    visitEquation (ctx: EquationContext): string
    {
        return this.visitChildren(ctx)
    }


    visitExpression (ctx: ExpressionContext): string
    {
        return this.visitChildren(ctx)
    }


    visitNumber (ctx: NumberContext): string
    {
        return ctx.text
    }
}



function parse_equation (equation_string: string)
{
    const input_stream = CharStreams.fromString(equation_string)
    const lexer = new datacurator_grammarLexer(input_stream)
    const token_stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    const parser = new datacurator_grammarParser(token_stream)

    return parser
}



function parser_to_javascript (parser: datacurator_grammarParser): string
{
    const parse_tree_result = parser.equation()
    const visitor = new Visitor()
    const result = visitor.visit(parse_tree_result)
    return result
}
```

With the following tests:

```js
function run_tests ()
{
    // Specs contain: [test_name, input, expected_result]
    const specs: [string, string, string][] = [
        ["Adding two numbers", "1 + 4", "( 1 + 4 )"],
        ["Adding three numbers", "1 + 4 + 2", "( 1 + 4 + 2 )"],
    ]

    specs.forEach(([test_name, input, expected_result]) =>
    {
        const parser = parse_equation(input)
        const result = parser_to_javascript(parser)
        test(result, expected_result, test_name)
    })
}

run_tests()
```

Both of the tests currently fail with:

```
fail: "(  +  )" !== "( -1 + 4 )"  Adding two numbers
fail: "( -14 +  )" !== "( -1 + 4 + 2 )"  Adding three numbers
```

How do I get antlr4ts to visit the expressions captured by the rule element labels `left` (and `right`)?  I was expecting the `visitAdditionOrSubtraction` to be called twice for the equation with 3 numbers being added but it's only called once.  And I was expecting the `visitNumber` function to be called twice and three times respectively but it's called 0 and once respectively.

If I change the `visitAdditionOrSubtraction` function body to be:

```js
    const left = ctx._left.text
    const right = ctx._right.text
    return `( ${left} ${ctx._operator.text} ${right} )`
```

I get:

```
pass  Adding two numbers
fail: "( 1+4 + 2 )" !== "( 1 + 4 + 2 )"  Adding three numbers
```

But this is also obviously not visiting the `visitAdditionOrSubtraction` function to process the `1 + 4` part, nor the `visitNumber` to process the individual numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to use `this.visit` and not `this.visitChildren`:

```
const left = this.visit(ctx._left)
const right = this.visit(ctx._left)
```

Taking the test case of adding 3 numbers: when `visitAdditionOrSubtraction` is first called the ctx.constructor shows it is `class AdditionOrSubtractionContext`.  The ctx._left.constructor is also `class AdditionOrSubtractionContext` as expected with the ctx._right.constructor being `class NumberContext`.

When `this.visitChildren` is called on these contexts only the contexts of their children is taken into account and in this case for "2" it skips calling `visitNumber` and calls `visitTerminal` which as it is not implemented returns the defaultResult of "".  If `visitTerminal` is implemented then it will display the numbers but still not call `visitAdditionOrSubtraction` twice.  Hence if you call `this.visit` it will work correctly.